# What is the Command Pattern in the book:Learning JavaScript Design Patterns

Tags: javascript

This problem comes from the usage of function closure, and the code snippet is as following:

```js
(function() {
    var carManager = {
        // request information
        requestInfo: function(model, id) {
            return "The information for " + model + " with ID " + id + " is foobar";
        },

        // purchase the car
        buyVehicle: function(model, id) {
            return "You have successfully purchased Item " + id + ", a " + model;
        },

        // arrange a viewing
        arrangeViewing: function(model, id) {
            return "You have successfully booked a viewing of " + model + " ( " + id + " ) ";
        }
    };

})()

carManager.execute = function(name) {
    return carManager[name] && carManager[name].apply(carManager, [].slice.call(arguments, 1));
};

carManager.execute("arrangeViewing", "Ferrari", "14523");
carManager.execute("requestInfo", "Ford Mondeo", "54323");
carManager.execute("requestInfo", "Ford Escort", "34232");
carManager.execute("buyVehicle", "Ford Escort", "34232");
```

The above codes is much like using function closure to replace the usage of new, 
but indeed when I use this example in jsfiddle(https://jsfiddle.net/abramhum/1cLpuf8n/1/), it not working.
The error message shows "Uncaught ReferenceError: carManager is not defined at window.onload". 
Is there any theorem or methodology about the usage of this way in JavaScript.
Is there any more detail materials to explain this. Thanks a lot.

Comment: well ... that code is useless, everything inside the IIFE is totally inaccessible from outside of it

Comment: That's because `carManager` is inside the IIFE. Maybe you meant `var carManager = (function() { return { … } })()`?

Comment: https://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#commandpatternjavascript The source doesn't really explain where the `.execute` calls are supposed to be in respect to the IIFE. Looks confusing (from a terminology/naming perspective, not from a syntax perspective)

Answer (score 0):

After re-build, the working example is as following:

```
(function() {
var carManager = {
    // request information
    requestInfo: function(model, id) {
        console.log("The information for " + model + " with ID " + id + " is foobar");
    },

    // purchase the car
    buyVehicle: function(model, id) {
        console.log("You have successfully purchased Item " + id + ", a " + model);
    },

    // arrange a viewing
    arrangeViewing: function(model, id) {
        console.log("You have successfully booked a viewing of " + model + " ( " + id + " ) ");
    }
};
carManager.execute = function(name) {
    return carManager[name] && carManager[name].apply(carManager, [].slice.call(arguments, 1));
};

carManager.execute("arrangeViewing", "Ferrari", "14523");
carManager.execute("requestInfo", "Ford Mondeo", "54323");
carManager.execute("requestInfo", "Ford Escort", "34232");
carManager.execute("buyVehicle", "Ford Escort", "34232");
})()
```